# passport js and mysql session issues

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, passport.js, express-session

I've seen this question asked alot but none of the cases seem applicable. I'm using passportjs with mysql and sessions. I'm trying to set up a sessions table in my db. I want the user to log in and it creates a session. Every time the user interacts with the api I want it to reset the expiration date on the session. When the user logs out I want the session destroyed in the db to prevent clutter. I can't seem to get req.user to last past when I login. Afterwards it returns as undefined on every other route that utilizes. it.

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const compression = require("compression");
const session = require("express-session");
const xss = require("xss-clean");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const passport = require("passport");
const pool = require("./services/db/dbConnection");
const { handleErrors } = require("./utils/handleErrors");
const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);
require("./services/auth/passportLocal");

// Required routes
const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute");
const errorRoute = require("./routes/errorRoute");
const sessionRoute = require("./routes/sessionRoute");
const floatTableRoute = require("./routes/floatTableRoute");
const rtcRoute = require("./routes/rtcRoute");

const app = express();

// Set path to .env file and check for errors
const dotenvConfig = dotenv.config();

//unable to load env file
if (dotenvConfig.error) {
  console.log("Error loading env file");
  process.exit(1); // Terminate the application if .env is not loaded
}

// Define required environment variables
const requiredEnvVars = [
  "NODE_ENV",
  "ALLOWED_ORIGIN",
  "SESSION_SECRET",
  "MYSQL_HOST",
  "MYSQL_USER",
  "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
  "MYSQL_DATABASE",
];

// Validate the presence of required environment variables
const missingEnvVars = requiredEnvVars.filter((envVar) => !process.env[envVar]);

//required enviroment variables are missing
if (missingEnvVars.length > 0) {
  console.log("required enviroment variables are missing at entry");
  process.exit(1); // Terminate the application if required variables are missing
}

// Compress res body to send JSON to client quicker
app.use(compression());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV != "production") {
  console.log("+-------------------------+");
  console.log("Running in developement...");
  console.log("Using morgan tiny...");
  app.use(morgan("tiny"));
} else {
  console.log("Using morgan combined...");
  app.use(morgan("combined"));
  console.log("+-------------------------+");
  console.log("Running in production...");
}

// Configure which domains can be access API
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGIN,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Allows req.body and req.query params able to be accessed
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Protect headers
app.use(helmet());

//------MySQL session store options------//
const sessionStoreOptions = {
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  createDatabaseTable: false,
  schema: {
    tableName: "Sessions",
    columnNames: {
      session_id: "session_id",
      expires: "expires",
      data: "data",
    },
  },
};

//-----session setup-----//
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    rolling: true,
    store: new MySQLStore(sessionStoreOptions),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2, // 2 hours
    },
  })
);

//----passport setup-----//
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Use xss-clean middleware
app.use(xss());

//-----routes-----//
app.use("/api/user", userRoute);
app.use("/api/session", sessionRoute);
app.use("/api/floatTable", floatTableRoute);
app.use("/api/rtc", rtcRoute);
app.use("*", errorRoute);

//-----middleware-----//
app.use(handleErrors);

// Test the MySQL connection
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  console.log("Testing MySQL connection...");
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error connecting to MySQL:", err);

    return;
  }
  console.log("Connected to MySQL...");
  console.log("+--------------------------+");

  // Release the connection
  connection.release();
});

module.exports = app;
```

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const pool = require("../db/dbConnection");

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const query =
      "SELECT UserEmail, UserName, UserID FROM Users WHERE UserID = ?";
    const params = [id];
    pool.execute(query, params, (err, result) => {
      //error in query
      if (err) {
        return done(err, null);
      }
      //no one found with ID
      else if (result.length === 0 || !result) {
        throw new Error("No user found");
      }
      //user is found with ID
      else if (result.length > 0) {
        const user = result[0];
        done(null, user);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err, null);
  }
});

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, (email, password, done) => {
    try {
      const query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserEmail = ?";
      const params = [email];
      pool.execute(query, params, async (err, result) => {
        //error in the query
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        //no user found
        else if (result.length === 0) {
          done(null, false, { message: "User not found" });
        }
        //user found
        else if (result.length > 0) {
          /* 
            result[0] data structure -> {UserID: '', UserEmail: '', UserName:'' Password: ''}
            --setting up the structure for the user obj that passport will use
            to monitor sessions--
          */
          const user = {
            id: result[0].UserID,
            email: result[0].UserEmail,
            password: result[0].Password,
            username: result[0].UserName,
          };

          //comparing body password to the hashed password
          const isValidLogin = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

          if (isValidLogin) {
            // Update LastLogin here before calling done
            const query = "UPDATE Users SET LastLogin = ? WHERE UserID = ?";
            const params = [new Date(), user.id];
            pool.execute(query, params, (err, result) => {
              if (err) {
                return done(err);
              } else {
                return done(null, user, { message: "Authentication Success" });
              }
            });
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: "Password is not valid" });
          }
        } else {
          done(null, false, { message: "Something is wrong" });
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return done(err, null);
    }
  })
);
```

```
/**
 * @desc log user out
 * @route POST api/user/logout
 * @access public
 */
const logoutUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    req.logout((err) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error("Failed to log out");
      }

      // Destroy the entire session
      req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error("Failed to destroy session");
        }

        console.log("user: " + req.user);
        console.log(req.session);

        // Send the response after successful logout and session destruction
        res.status(200).json({ response: { message: "Logout successful" } });
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

/**
 * @desc demo with deserialization
 * @route GET api/user/currentUser
 * @access public
 */
const getCurrentUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated(), req.user);
    console.log(req.session);
    res.status(200).json({
      user: { id: req.user.id, email: req.user.email },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Above are my app.js where I initialize my session, my passport.js where I set up login for the user, and my userController.js that has a couple of relevant controller functions for routes. Please help me solve this and also any best practice techniques I could apply would be super helpful!